# Can I query a record with multiple associated records that fit certain criteria?

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two tables, `Show`, `Character`. Each Show has_many Characters.

```
class Show < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :characters

class Character < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :show
```

What I want to do is return the results of a Show that is associated with multiple Characters that fit certain criteria.

For example, I want to be able to return a list of Shows that have as characters both Batman and Robin. Not Batman OR Robin, Batman AND Robin.

So the query should be something like

```
Show.includes(:characters).where(characters: {'name = ? AND name = ?', "Batman", "Robin"})
```

But this returns an error. Is there a syntax for this that would work?

**UPDATE**

The query

```
Show.includes(:characters).where('characters.name = ? AND characters.name = ?', "Batman", "Robin")
```

returns a value of 0, even though there are definitely Shows associated with both Batman and Robin.

Comment: Do any of these proposed solutions work for you?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using plain SQL, one solution is :

```
select s. * 
from shows as s 
join characters as c1 on (s.id=c1.show_id) 
join characters as c2 on (s.id=c2.show_id) 
where c1.name='Batman' 
and   c2.name='Robin';
```

Using Arel, I would translate as :

```
Show.joins('join characters as c1 on shows.id=c1.show_id').joins('join
characters as c2 on shows.id=c2.show_id').where('c1.name = "Batman"').where(
'c2.name="Robin"')
```

Comment: I guess it doesn't scale with a larger amount of common actors. An aggregate function could be another choice.

Answer (score 6):

So you'll have to get a little fancy with SQL here; especially if you want it to be performant and handle different types of matchers.

```
select count(distinct(characters.name)) as matching_characters_count, shows.* from shows
  inner join characters on characters.show_id = shows.id and (characters.name = 'Batman' or characters.name = 'Robin')
group by shows.id
having matching_characters_count = 2
```

To translate into ActiveRecord

```
Show.select('count(distinct(characters.name)) as matching_characters_count, shows.*').
   joins('inner join characters on characters.show_id = shows.id and (characters.name = "Batman" or characters.name = "Robin")').
   group('shows.id').
   having('matching_characters_count = 2')
```

Then you'd probably do a pass with interpolation and then AREL it up; so you wouldn't be building string queries.

Comment: Simple `count(*)` instead of `count(distinct(characters.name))` would produce correct result as well.

Comment: It can be simplified a little as `Show.select('count(distinct(characters.name)) as matching_characters_count, shows.*').joins(:characters).where('characters.name = "Batman" or characters.name = "Robin"').group('shows.id').having('matching_characters_count = 2')`

Answer (score 4):

A plain SQL solution using aggregate functions. The SQL statements returns the ID values of the ´shows´ records you are looking for.

```
SELECT c.show_id
  FROM characters c
 WHERE c.name IN ('Batman','Robin')
 GROUP BY c.show_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT c.name) = 2
```

You can put this statement into a `select_values()` call and then grab the `shows` with the values of the returned array.

Comment: How would I integrate this into a rails document?

Answer (score 4):

I think this must work:

```
super_heroes = ['Batman', 'Robin']

Show.where(
  id: Character.select(:show_id).where(name: super_heroes).group(:show_id)
       .having("count(distinct characters.name) = #{super_heroes.size}")
)
```

I just write the @sschmeck query in a Rails way, as a subquery, and add a `super_heroes` var to show how it can be scaled.

Comment: Thank you. The results of the show query should be used to select corresponding `Show` objects, just to answer the question above.

Answer (score 3):

Reduce the number of entries in the query as soon as possible is basic idea to get a better query in performance.

```
Show.where("id IN (( SELECT show_id FROM characters WHERE name = 'Batman') INTERSECT (SELECT show_id FROM characters WHERE name = 'Robin'))")
```

In above query, the 1st sub query gets the 'show_id' for 'Batman', the next one gets the 'show_id' for 'Robin'. In my opinion, just a few characters match the condition after doing 'INTERSECT'. Btw, you can use [explain](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#running-explain) command in 'rails db' for choosing what is better solution.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for this:

```
Show.includes(:characters).where(characters: {name: ["Batman", "Robin"]})
```

*or*

```
Show.includes(:characters).where('characters.name IN ?', ["Batman", "Robin"]).references(:characters)
```

The `references` is required because we're using a *string* in the `where` method.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but this query always returns an empty relation for me, even though there are definitely multiple Shows in my Database associated with both Batman and Robin.

Comment: This query will be always empty because a charatecter cannot be Batman and Robin at the same time...

Comment: Very true, Didn't really notice that! I've tweaked the code to work better. Thanks!

Comment: Strange, I think this query just shouldn't work, since `includes` is supposed to make another query for fetching characters, so `characeters.name` shouldn't be available in that query.

Comment: It should load the association in the SQL. See more information here: https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes.
Also, you could always do `Show.includes(:characters).where('characters.name IN ?', ["Batman", "Robin"]).to_sql` to see what ActiveRecord is going to request from your database.

Comment: It also matters if you want to do an inner join or outer join. You could use `joins` (inner join) instead of `includes` (outer join). See more: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-eager-loaded-associations

Also noted that because we're using a string, you'd have to add `.references(:characters)` to your query so that Rails knows you're wanting characters in the query.

Answer (score 0):

So first of all, Why is your approach is wrong?
So in the "characters_shows" table you can find records that looks like this

```
show_id    name    character_id    character_name
 1     first show        1         batman
 2     second            1         batman
 1     first show        2         robin
 1     first show        3         superman
```

As you can see there will never be a case where the character name is batman and robin at the same row

Another approach will be something like this

```
names = ["Batman", "Robin"]

Show.joins(:characters).where(characters: {name: names}).group("shows.id").having("COUNT(*) = #{names.length}")
```